# Create and Run an AllowanceCrowdSale With Zeppelin-OS Contracts

Tags: tokens, crowdsale, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-sdk

I use the openzeppelin library:
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/tree/v1.12.0

### token

I create a BurnableToken:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

import 'openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/StandardBurnableToken.sol';

contract TestBurnableToken is StandardBurnableToken {
    string public name = "TestCoinBurnable";
    string public symbol = "tcb";
    uint8 public decimals = 18;

    uint256 public totalSupply;
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    constructor (
        uint256 initialSupply
    ) public {
        totalSupply = initialSupply * 10 ** uint256(decimals);  // Update total supply with the decimal amount
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;                // Give the creator all initial tokens
    }
}
```

the creator receives all the tokens.

## crowdsale

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

import './TestBurnableToken.sol';
import 'openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/emission/AllowanceCrowdsale.sol';
import 'openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/validation/TimedCrowdsale.sol';


contract TestBurnableCrowdsale is TimedCrowdsale, AllowanceCrowdsale {
    constructor
        (
            uint256 _openingTime,
            uint256 _closingTime,
            uint256 _rate,
            address _wallet,
            StandardBurnableToken _token
        )
        public
        Crowdsale(_rate, _wallet, _token)
        TimedCrowdsale(_openingTime, _closingTime)
        AllowanceCrowdsale(_wallet) {
        }
}
```

### deployment

```
const TestBurnableToken = artifacts.require("./TestBurnableToken.sol");
const TestBurnableCrowdsale = artifacts.require("./TestBurnableCrowdsale.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {

const openingTime = web3.eth.getBlock('latest').timestamp + 30; // two secs in the future
const closingTime = openingTime + 60 *15 // 15min
const rate = new web3.BigNumber(1000); // only ints > 0, rate seems not to be inverse
const wallet = accounts[0];


console.log("Deploying openingTime: ", openingTime, " closingTime ", closingTime, " rate ", rate, " wallet ", wallet);

return deployer
    .then(() => {
        return deployer.deploy(TestBurnableToken, 10000);
    })
    .then(() => {
        return deployer.deploy(
            TestBurnableCrowdsale,
            openingTime,
            closingTime,
            rate,
            wallet,
            TestBurnableToken.address
        );
    });
};
```

### truffle console

```
// The account that created the tokens
creator = web3.eth.accounts[0]

// The account that will buy Test tokens.
purchaser = web3.eth.accounts[2]

// The address of the Test token instance that was created when the crowdsaleInstance contract was deployed
// assign the result of TestBurnableCrowdsale.deployed() to the variable crowdsaleInstance
TestBurnableCrowdsale.deployed().then(inst => { crowdsaleInstance = inst })

crowdsaleInstance.token().then(addr => { tokenAddress = addr } )
tokenAddress

TestBurnableTokenInstance = TestBurnableToken.at(tokenAddress)

//balances before
TestBurnableTokenInstance.balanceOf(creator).then(balance => web3.fromWei(balance.toString(10)))
//this shows 10000 because 10000 tokens have been created by account[0]

TestBurnableTokenInstance.balanceOf(purchaser).then(balance => web3.fromWei(balance.toString(10)))
//this shows 0, no tokens have been bought yet


//account 0 now approves tokens to be sold
TestBurnableTokenInstance.approve(crowdsaleInstance.address,web3.toWei(1000, "ether"))
crowdsaleInstance.remainingTokens().then(balance => web3.fromWei(balance.toString(10)))
//shows that 1000 tokens of 10000 have been approved for selling

//buy and balances after buying
crowdsaleInstance.sendTransaction({ from: purchaser, value: web3.toWei(1, "ether")})
// Here I get an error: Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert // I also tried 0.1 and 10000 to make sure it has nothing to do with the rate
```

Question: Why is the last console call failing, the tokens have been approved by `account[0]` to be accessed by the crowdsale contract.

### Edit

I used truffles debug function with a weird result:

```
31:     returns (bool)
32:   {
33:     require(_value <= balances[_from]);
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 

debug(develop:0xefe253c5...)> v

   _from: '0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57'
     _to: '0xc5fdf4076b8f3a5357c5e395ab970b5b54098fef'
  _value: 1000000000000000000
        : true

debug(develop:0xefe253c5...)> 

StandardToken.sol:

35:     require(_to != address(0));
36: 
37:     balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^             

debug(develop:0xefe253c5...)> v

   _from: '0x0de0b6b3a7640000'
     _to: '0x0de0b6b3a7640000'
  _value: 816
        : true
```

Basically the values of `_from`, `to`, `_value` change between the lines `33` and `37`.

```
require(_value <= balances[_from]);
require(_value <= allowed[_from][msg.sender]);
require(_to != address(0));

balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was required to change `balanceOf` to `balances` otherwise the fn is overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are confusing how the `approve` function works. The `approve` is basically only used in combination with the `transferFrom` function to approve transfer of tokens - not the purchase.

You can either play around with Truffle's debug functionality or just simply comment out `require` statements until you find the culprit.

I don't have experience with the `AllowanceCrowdsale` (https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/v1.12.0/contracts/crowdsale/emission/AllowanceCrowdsale.sol) but my guess is that a `require` fails somewhere around there (probaby around `_deliverTokens` ).

Comment: The number of `remainingTokens` in the crowdsale contract is the same amount as the number I specified in the approve call, so I think it enables the crowdsale contract to `transferFrom ` the approving wallet, which would make sense.

I will look into debug function.

Comment: I debugged the contract but now I'm even more confused. Everything looks fine so far but in the end values seem to change. I think solidity is synchronous so there should be no problem with race conditions etc.